# Jenkins : Windows build to Windows host : which plugin to use?

Tags: jenkins

I have found many examples of Linux to Windows or OSX to Windows, but battling to find how to copy build files from a Windows server installation of Jenkins, to the
Windows server which will host the website.

I tried Copy Artifact Plugin - but it seems this is used to copy other builds into the current build - is this correct?

Or can it be used to copy the build that just execute to a remote Windows folder?

What should I use to copy to another Windows server?
I would like to not use batch files. Can/should powershell be used?

The idea would be to copy the files to a timestamped folder on the hosting Windows server
e.g.

```
xcopy *.* \\MyHostingServer\Temp
```

Then only after everything has copied successfully - to copy the files from `MyHostingServer\Temp` into the correct web folder. This is to prevent the deployment to the web folder if e.g. network connection was lost halfway.

I am having a really hard time getting Windows specific information.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use two jobs:

- build job is running on the first Windows server. Archive your build files as an artifacts to the job
- deployment job should run on second Windows server. You can use  "Copy artifacts from another project" to get your build files locally (on second server)

Comment: Thanks Ivan. If this is not possible for whatever reason, do you think I should investigate powershell scripting? After a build has been completed then copy the files to Temp Location and then after that to proper location e.g. inetpub/wwwroot/myapp (just an example and not point of contention)